# How to use Time Data type only in Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I use time as datatype in my rails migration but when I am retrieving it in model
 it includes date. I wanted to be able to compute time difference without date. 
Any way I can do to make my model return time only ?
I wanted this  `03:15:00` not this `2000-01-01 05:54:42`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert a Datetime object into a Time object, you can use `Time.parse`.

```
date_and_time = Time.now               # 2000-01-01 05:54:42
time_only = Time.parse(date_and_time)  # 05:54:42
```

Comment: TypeError (no implicit conversion of Time into String) and I'm running Rails 5.0.7

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `time` data type for a column in your database migration you should be fine. Rails fills the missing fields (in this case year, month, day) with default values since the data type requires them. Since all responses get these default values you should be able to calculate time differences without date since all values have the same default value. If you want to get the time as string back in the format you want you can use `#strftime` method.

Eg:

```
time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```